# Any memory leak (or over-instantiation of objects) when using iOS Storyboard Seque "Model" or "Push" style?

Tags: ios, storyboard, push, modal-dialog

Let's say I'm developing a simple iPhone app with two screens: Login and Register screens. Within the Login screen, it has the "Register" button which takes to the Register screen. Likewise, within the Register screen, it has the "Login" button which takes to the Login screen. All is implemented using iOS Storyboard Segue "Modal" style.

The question is: does keep adding a new view to a stack everytime a view controller is presented by a segue "Modal" style? So, if I repeatly switch between the Login and Register screens, will it instantiates new objects everytime and keeps accumulating with an internal array container (ie. stack)?

Further, if I change the style to "push", how will the situation be like to the similar question? Doesn't "push" keeps adding new view objects to the top everytime it is "pushed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@trapper is absolutely correct. You segues will stack them up, but it won't leak as long as you dismiss your "modal" with `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` or pop your pushed view controller with `popViewControllerAnimated:`. If you erroneously have a segue from your login/register screen back to the main view, then that memory won't be released (which isn't technically a leak, but it's wrong and you won't release the memory).

Comment: I used "[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];" and it seemed to have no effect. Further, after the second view is done, I called "[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];" and the previous view is still there. I thought it was dismissed and it should not be there ???

Comment: You only use thedismissViewControllerAnimated method to dismiss modal views. Is your view for which it's having no effect modal, or is a view that your segue just pushed onto your stack (in which case you use  popViewControllerAnimated, not dismissViewControllerAnimated, to get back to the previous view)? Regarding the  popViewControllerAnimated returning you to the previous one, that's what it's supposed to do (I'm not sure if your latter point is related to the confusion about the dismissViewControllerAnimated method, or something else, so let me know).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will keep stacking them up either way.

Just to clarify though, it wont cause any leaks.