# How do I clean up UIViewController instances created by Storyboard Segues?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple app that consists of a sidebar menu (I'm using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)) which contains a table view, each cell of which has a segue pointing to a UIWebViewController.  So the user can pull open the sidebar and switch between various configured mobile sites (among other things).

I've got it working fine, but I've noticed that, as I switch back and forth between the sidebar tabs, the number of controllers that get pinged during a memory warning keeps growing.  It appears that a new UIWebVewController is created each time I switch tabs, which is fine, except that the framework code appears to be keeping a list of each controller that is created and is never letting go, causing the memory to keep climbing.  I'm sure there's a way that I can clean up that list, but I haven't found it yet…

So, my questions are

1. What is it that is holding on to references to each UIViewController that is created, and where can I find/access that?
2. How do I clean that up?
3. **What framework code/class is in charge of calling `didReceiveMemoryWarning:`, and where does that guy get the list of controllers that need to receive the warning?**

In searching around, I came across [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584601/), which hints that `popViewControllerAnimated:` might be how I can cleanup unneeded controllers, but I'm not sure which object I should be calling that on, since I don't know the answer to #1 or #3 above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, in my case, the thing holding a reference to my controllers (question #1) was a scheduled NSTimer that the controller was creating with *itself* as the target. To clean it up (question #2), I needed to invalidate the timer prior to leaving the controller (in my case, in the `viewWillDisappear:` method) via `[myTimer invalidate]`.

I still haven't found the answer to question #3, and I'm still curious to know how Apple keeps track of which controllers are still alive and, therefore, need the memory warning, but question #3 isn't as important to me, anymore, now that my memory leak is gone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if SWRevealViewController is holding on to the View Controller it is pushing on the stack. Usually you would create a dictionary of UINavigationControllers each one for your ViewController and then use the dictionary to retrieve the UINavigationControllers each time you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. SWRevealViewController may be holding on to controllers, but even if it is, it's not the ONLY place holding references. Apple's code is what is calling didReceiveMemoryWarning:, therefore, Apple's code must *also* be holding references (either that or Apple is calling a delegate method to find that information. If so, what is that method?). It's those references that I need to clean up. If Apple holds on to them forever, then that's a memory leak. There has to be a way to tell Apple's code that a controller is no longer needed so that Apple can let go of the reference.